# ruby 1.8.7 makes and installs on Centos 5.5 but won't run

Tags: centos5, ruby

I've downloaded `ruby-1.8.7.p334 ruby-1.8.7.p334.tar.gz` from `ftp.ruby-lang.org`, and decompressed it.

When I did `./configure` , it complained about no suitable c compiler, so I did`yum install gcc`.

Then I went back to do

```
./configure
make
make install
```

It's all gone OK with no errors, `ruby -v`gives me `-bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory`.

`which ruby` returns `/usr/local/bin/ruby'. Below is a listing of /usr/local/bin

```
[root@ttsdev bin]# ll
total 2684
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3882 Apr  5 13:17 erb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     379 Apr  5 13:17 irb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1543 Apr  5 13:17 rdoc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1491 Apr  5 13:17 ri
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2721701 Apr  5 13:17 ruby
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     153 Apr  5 13:17 testrb
```

Any ideas why it's not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more things required that just gcc.  If you dont want to go the RVM angle you can use the instructions [here](http://www.freshblurbs.com/install-ruby-1-9-centos).   It is for 1.9 but could be applied to 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to manage your rubies - it will install, configure everything for you.

Comment: and gemcutter for your gems!

Comment: Yup. If you're not using RVM, your doing it wrong. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> It's all gone OK with no errors, ruby -vgives me -bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory.
>
> which ruby returns `/usr/local/bin/ruby'

Looks like a bad symlink. Not sure why, but looks like ruby -v is trying to read a link to a ruby binary at /usr/bin/ruby, because it's not there it's failing with the error you see.

If /usr/local/bin/ruby is indeed where ruby is installed, quick and dirty fix is to create a symlink to it in /usr/bin:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: +1 for actally trying to answer the question I asked